# My Hyundai wont start but I still get power

Tags: hyundai, no-crank-no-start, santa-fe

I have a 2015 Hyundai Santa Fe sport and I was driving on the highway and suddenly it just died out of nowhere, so I put it neutral till I could stop on the side of the freeway. And I tried and tried to start it but nothing. I still have all power to the vehicle but it won’t turn over or anything of the sort. I had power to the vehicle even when it just suddenly died. I got the car towed home and put some jumper cables on it just in case it had low voltage and still nothing it won’t even turn over but again still have power to it. When I want on the side of the road I tried to start it and I seen some smoke come from the engine bay and I couldn’t find where it was coming from. Smelled kinda like coolant but I checked that and it was all good.I took a look at all fuses and everything

Comment: there are just too many things that can cause an engine to not run, from mechanical failures (a part broke in the engine) to an electrical fault that keeps something from working.

Answer (score 0):

The same exact thing happened to my 2013 Hyundai Santa Fe Sport on the freeway.

I took it to the Hyundai dealership and they fixed it for free because apparently those Santa Fe have a recall for engine issues that cause the car to shut down and the engine breaks down and can catch fire. So take it there and they should replace your entire engine for free even out of warranty.

Comment: Here is a link to that recall --> https://repairpal.com/recall/17V226000